# Titan 1.0.0 TitanFactory.open() Hook creation trace error(?)

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying out Titan 1.0.0 with cassandra 2.1.2.

I keep getting a long debug trace and a strange error from gremlin when opening a graph (using TitanFactroy.open()):

...

17:54:36.551 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.g.database.StandardTitanGraph - Installed shutdown hook Thread[Thread-3,5,main] java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.(StandardTitanGraph.java:156) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]   at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:74) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]   at com.ibm.titantest.graph.WriteToGraph.main(WriteToGraph.java:27) [classes/:na] 17:54:36.646 [pool-19-thread-1] DEBUG c.t.t.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog - MessagePuller configured with ReadMarker timestamp slightly ahead of read lag time; waiting for the clock to catch up 17:54:41.650 [pool-19-thread-1] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.CassandraTransaction - Created CassandraTransaction@6e234a4a[read=QUORUM,write=QUORUM] 17:54:46.652 [pool-19-thread-1] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.CassandraTransaction - Created CassandraTransaction@2c7b5ce[read=QUORUM,write=QUORUM]

Managed to fix it in the gremlin console by creating a file called logback.xml in the titan root folder containing:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

(solution taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/gremlin$20history/aureliusgraphs/tZ0XhwJY9jQ/0t2UP4FlBAAJ))

But how can i solve it for when running gremlin from eclipse?